# PHP looping through excel cells

Tags: php, laravel, phpspreadsheet

Hello i'm trying to extract some data from an excel file using Spreadsheet php, but it's not working and not filling the array with extracted data.

My code:

```
$request->validate([
    'uploaded_file' => 'required|file|mimes:xls,xlsx'
]);

$excel_file = $request->file('uploaded_file');
$file = IOFactory::load($excel_file->getRealPath());

$worksheet = $file->getActiveSheet();


$data_grid = []; 
$data_detail = [];

$data_grid['codice_cliente'] = $file->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B3')->getValue();
$data_grid['codice_destinazione'] = $file->getActiveSheet()->getCell('G3')->getValue();
$data_grid['data_ordine'] = '2022-07-15 15:32:04';
$data_grid['data_richiesta'] = '2022-06-15';
$data_grid['note_consegna'] = $file->getActiveSheet()->getCell('G5')->getValue();
$data_grid['id_agente'] = Auth::user()->id;
$data_grid['canale'] = 'B';
$data_grid['tipologia'] = 'O';
$data_grid['edi_id'] = 1;
$data_grid['edi_company'] = 'C';
$data_grid['edi_doctype'] = 'D';
$data_grid['jde_id'] = 2;
$data_grid['jde_company'] = 'E';
$data_grid['jde_doctype'] = 'F';
$data_grid['stato_ordine'] = 1;
$data_grid['total_order'] = 99.99;
$data_detail['nr_riga'] = 50;


$row = 8;
foreach($worksheet as $data) {
    
    $row++;
    
    $data_detail['codice_articolo'] = $data->getCell("A$row")->getValue();
    $data_detail['quantita'] = $data->getCell("B$row")->getValue();
    $data_detail['prezzo'] = $data->getActiveSheet()->getCell("C$row")->getValue();
}
```

The foreach loop has to extract all values from those specific columns for each row.. but i get array key error.

Excel:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach loop doesn't make sense. Just use a for loop and it's `$worksheet->getCell()`, rather than `$data->getCell()`

```
$worksheet = $file->getActiveSheet();

...

$highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

for($row = 8; $row < $highestRow; $row++) {
    $data_detail['codice_articolo'] = $worksheet->getCell("A$row")->getValue();
    $data_detail['quantita'] = $worksheet->getCell("B$row")->getValue();
    $data_detail['prezzo'] = $worksheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell("C$row")->getValue();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much it works! But so the db doens't save records of each row from those columns

Comment: That's a new question :)